# CSS only - Card flip looping animation with multiple divs?

Tags: css

I want to do card flip looping effect with multiple divs, css only.

Everytime the card flip, show next div. (No matter how many divs are there.)

I've tried but I just can't figure out the timing between divs.

https://codepen.io/impetusjj/pen/JjNyodo?editors=1100

```
.card {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;

  div {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
  }
  .one {
    background: pink;
    animation: flip 6s linear infinite;
  }
  .two {
    background: yellow;
    animation: flip 6s linear infinite;
    // transform: rotateY(180deg);
    animation-delay: 1.5s;
  }
  .three {
    background: black;
    animation: flip 6s linear infinite;
    // transform: rotateY(180deg);
    animation-delay: 3s;
  }
}

@keyframes flip {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
  }
  33.33% {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
  }
}
```

Someone please help me?

Comment: Could you describe a bit more what effect you want. Is one card to turn over to show its face, then turn to show its back then the next card to turn to show its face and then its back and so on? As if it was one card but with the face color different the next time?

Comment: @AHaworth yes! As if all of those divs are one card, but everytime the card turns and shows other side, it shows next div (if there's no next div, return to show the first div, and so on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For three card 'faces' we need each face to show for one third of the total animation time so the animation delays need to be 0s, 2s, 4s for a total animation time of 6s.

For its 2 seconds the face is to show and it must show when rotated between -90s (ie head on to the viewer) and 90deg.

At other times the face isn't to be seen at all.

This snippet starts each face off at -90deg and not showing (opacity: 0). Each face animates after its initial delay, getting opacity: 1 and rotating for one third of the total animation time and then disappearing with opacity: 0.

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  perspective: 1500px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.card div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  animation: flip 6s linear infinite;
  opacity: 0;
  /* ADDED */
}

.card .one {
  background: pink;
}

.card .two {
  background: yellow;
  animation-delay: 2s;
}

.card .three {
  background: black;
  animation-delay: 4s;
}

@keyframes flip {
  0% {
    transform: rotateY(-90deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  33.33% {
    transform: rotateY(90deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  33.34% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

</style>
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="one">
  </div>
  <div class="two">
  </div>
  <div class="three">
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: the question asks for CSS-only solution however many faces there are. This is possible as can be seen here if you know the number of divs in advance, but unfortunately CSS does not allow the %s in keyframe definitions to depend on a calc, so we have to calculate the %s in advance depending on the number of faces. The delays could be calculated if a CSS variable --n = the number of faces were set.

Comment: My god, you're a life saver!!! Thank you so much for this quick and detail explanation!

Comment: Thanks, I had a typo in the original which meant the perspective wasn't showing, now corrected.

Comment: Is there a way or a hack to set easing like 'ease-out' so that the easing starts at 0deg, end at 180deg?

Comment: Not sure I understand, a face shows from -90deg to 90deg not 0 to 180dg.

Comment: yes, I know that is the logic. But I wonder if I could set easing like this, for example. [codepen sample link, please check!](https://codepen.io/impetusjj/pen/poPWWNM) So that the easing starts when the card is at 0 deg, easing ends when the card is at 180deg.
Right now, if I set easing besides linear, because it starts at -90deg and ends at 90deg, it's not a desired effect. I'm just wondering if this is possible as well.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. The face is never at 180 (you'd just be seeing its back if it was).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235171/discussion-between-jaye-park-and-a-haworth).